# nd array to string and string to nd array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have the following problem:
I want to convert my nd_array to a string variable but I also want to restore the structure. For example my nd_array looks like
nd_array = [[array_best, float_best]] array_best is a numpy array with 2 entries and float_best is a float variable.

> [[array([2.54974085, 5.45954157]), -0.741455078125], [array([2.55141016, 5.40955301]), -0.73046875], [array([2.55466028, 5.40582758]), -0.69287109375]]

I tried to split the nd_array into smaller arrays and then to string but I sort the nd_array so in case of multiple arrays I have to store the mapping. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the problem statement, my solution would be:

```py
import numpy as np

array_of_arrays = [[np.array([2.54974085, 5.45954157]), -0.741455078125], [np.array([2.55141016, 5.40955301]), -0.73046875], [np.array([2.55466028, 5.40582758]), -0.69287109375]]
my_string = ""
for an_array in array_of_arrays:
    for element in an_array:
        if isinstance(element, float):
            my_string = my_string + str(element) + ","
        else:
            for a_float in element:
                my_string = my_string + str(a_float) + ","
            
my_string = my_string[:-1]
```

If this not what you requested, please provide further information